# React linter airbnb proptypes array

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes, linter, eslint-config-airbnb

I have the following `PropTypes`:

```
SmartTable.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  cols: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  rows: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

but the linter says me:

`Prop type "array" is forbidden`, how can I change it?

Comment: The question is what you want to change: The issue which the warning is trying to highlight, or just the warning itself? If the former, i.e. you do want to follow the best practices suggested by the eslint rule, the answer from @FacundoGFlores is correct, and you should make the types more specific. If you don't care about the issue, and just want to suppress the warning, then simply disable the rule.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A possible solution for this (but I think it is not smart):

```
SmartTable.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  cols: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string),
  rows: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string),
};
```

Comment: Why is this not smart? In statically typed languages arrays are declared with the type they contain e.g. `string[]` or `MyObject[]` so it would make sense to tell `React.PropTypes` what type your array is.

Answer (score 17):

One of the solution which worked for me:

If you want arrays:

```
SmartTable.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  cols: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array),
  rows: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array),
};
```

For Objects and Arrays, It can be:

```
SmartTable.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  cols: PropTypes.instanceOf(Object),
  rows: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array),
};
```

Comment: It works, but it's bypassing the actual issue: The reason that eslint rule exists is so you don't have overly-general prop types that don't mean much (https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md). All this solution accomplishes is allow you to keep the overly-general types while implicitly disabling the warning. But if you really intend to ignore it, there's nothing stopping you from simply disabling the rule explicitly in your eslint config.

Answer (score 11):

If the array of cols and rows are objects I like using shape so it could be something like this.

```js
    SmartTable.propTypes = {
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      cols: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        value: PropTypes.string,
       })
      rows: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        value: PropTypes.string,
       })
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Short versions:

for Array
`PropTypes.shape([])`

for Object
`PropTypes.shape({})`

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to get around the array forbidden error as well:

```
PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any.isRequired).isRequired
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add comment eslint-disable-line

```
someVal: PropTypes.array, // eslint-disable-line
```

Comment: This is a good temporary solution, although not one that will work for those of us with clients that forbid this. There are reasons for eslint rules, unfortunately.